# Add additional data to jquery.autocomplete in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, jquery-autocomplete

I'm writing RoR application and I have working autocomplete. In page.coffee I have this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: "/autocomplete_source"
```

In the form I have also #select combobox in addition to the #search textbox and I'd need to pass the value of selected item as 'data' into the jQuery.autocomplete method.

In short - I need to restrict searched values by the value of combobox selected item.

How can I pass it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: '/autocomplete_source',
    data: {}
```

And if you want a compltex data object, you can do this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
    source: '/autocomplete_source',
    data:
      key: 'value',
      key2: 'value'
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I read it? I was expecting it in the controller "autocomplete_source" in the method "index" in the params[:key], but there is any such key in the params..

Comment: Can you link to the actual library that you're using? Because according to this documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete you shouldn't see it, and there is no `data` option.

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI v1.10.3 and jQuery v1.11.2. So if this is not the way, how can I filter autocomplete results based by the dropdownlist selected item?

Comment: I haven't used jquery autocomplete that much. So I don't have an answer to that.